# finding the product of sides in a traingle using function with 2 variables

Tags: functions

ABC is a triangle,M is a variable point inside it.
Let AB=c,CA=b,BC=a.
Let x,y,z and alpha be the respective areas of the triangles MBC,MCA,MAB,and ABC.
Let I,J,and K be respectively the orthogonal projections of M on AB,BC,and CA.
the question is:
Using function of two variables ,find the maximum of the product of the distances between the sides of the triangle ABC and the point M (MI.MJ.MK)

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

ok the answer is:
alpha = x+y+z so z=alpha-x-y
but MI.MJ.MK=(8xyz)/abc since z=(MI.AB)/2 and so on for x and y;
so MI.MJ.MK=(8/(abc))*(x*y*(alpha-x-y)),where (8/(abc)) and alpha are constants since ABC is a fixed triangle but M is variable.
thus let f(x,y)=(x*y*(alpha-x-y));
now search for the minimum of f and thus you will find the maximum of the required product;
sure the answer is not complete for here but all this is just a hint and you should continue from here